# Python telegram bot: Access to contact information

Tags: python, django, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Following code requests location and contact from user:

```
def contact(bot, update):
    dp = DjangoTelegramBot.dispatcher

    con_keyboard = KeyboardButton(text="send_contact", request_contact=True)
    loc_keyboard = KeyboardButton(text="send_location", request_location=True)
    custom_keyboard = [[ con_keyboard ,loc_keyboard]]
    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(custom_keyboard)

    bot.sendMessage(update.message.chat_id, 
              text="Would you mind sharing your location and contact with me", 
              reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

My question is how can I access to phone number after user clicks on send_contact button?
PS: I am using [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) and [django-telegrambot](https://github.com/jlmadurga/django-telegram-bot)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure with `django-telegrambot`. But if I'm not wrong your `reply_markup` is the one under `python-telegram-bot`. When the button is pressed, the user's phone number will be sent to your bot as a [`Contact`](http://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.contact.html#telegram.Contact) object. You can catch it with a [`MessageHandler`](http://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.messagehandler.html) and a [`Filters.contact`](http://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters.contact) filter.

```
from telegram.ext import MessageHander, Filters

def contact_callback(bot, update):
    contact = update.effective_message.contact
    phone = contact.phone_number

dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.contact, contact_callback))
```