# How to confirm if a phone number belongs to a user_id in telegram bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm working on a project where the user enters their phone number on a website. And the conformation is done through a telegram bot, which the user initiates a conversation with first. The user sends the confirmation code displayed on the site to the bot.

So here is my question, is there any way that I can compare the phone number the user provided with the confirmation code message the user sent to the bot? Or is there any way that I can get the `user_id` from the phone number, the user provided, so that I can compare it with the message sent by the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send `Keyboard` with `request_contact=True` that will ask user to share phone number ([documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton)).

Then your bot can get an `Update` with it ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46481601/3722635) how to do that) and compare with desired phone number.